# Java - Panels in a BoxLayout Panel separated

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, border-layout, boxlayout

I have this code:

```
    //Panell Order
    JPanel jorder = new JPanel();
    jorder.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jorder, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    jorder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Order"));
    jorder.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,250));
    //Panell 1
    JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
    ((FlowLayout)jp1.getLayout()).setAlignment(FlowLayout.CENTER);
    JLabel jusuari = new JLabel("User name:         ");
    JLabel jnom = new JLabel("edetorres");
    jp1.add(jusuari);
    jp1.add(jnom);
    //Panell 2
    JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
    ((FlowLayout)jp2.getLayout()).setAlignment(FlowLayout.CENTER);
    JLabel jproduct = new JLabel("Product:          ");
    JLabel jcomanda = new JLabel("Tallat");
    jp2.add(jproduct);
    jp2.add(jcomanda);
    //Panel 3
    JPanel jp3 = new JPanel();
    JButton jserve = new JButton("Serve");
    jserve.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    jp3.add(jserve);
    //Afegir al panell Order
    jorder.add(jp1);
    jorder.add(jp2);
    jorder.add(jp3);
```

And the problem is that it returns a panel with the three panels (jp1,jp2,jp3) separated, like this:

[image: JPanels image]

How can I do for have together these 3 panels?

Comment: What is the expected result exactly ?

Comment: A BoxLayout will distribute its components even over the total length. Set the component sizes or such.

Comment: I want to have these 3 panels together, not separated by spaces

Comment: I just solved it! I used a GridBagLayout! Thanks!